# Selector de carpetas desde navegador (component folder chooser)

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, angular

Necesito crear una aplicación angular que me permita seleccionar carpetas para enviar la ruta a otro microservicio u endpoint.
El problema es que he leído que por razones de seguridad no es posible hacerlo con html o javascript puro. Se puede combinándolo con java o flash pero trae mucho trabajo y problemas de compatibilidad.

He visto este tutorial: 
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-explorer-component/#using-the-fileservice-to-feed-the-fileexplorer,
que es un explorador de archivos, pero no es exactamente lo que quiero. Yo necesito que tenga un botón para enviar esa ruta a otro módulo del proyecto, pero como soy principiante en angular no sé si me sirve ese tutorial.

¿Alguien que sepa angular puede decirme si me serviría ese tutorial, u otro modo, para agregarle un botón y que haga lo que necesitamos?

Comment: El tutorial crea carpetas del lado del servidor, eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: Necesito que las carpetas las pueda seleccionar para enviar la ruta a un endpoint, o microserivicio. La parte de crearlas no  la necesito pero quiero saber si teniendo este selector podría enviar las rutas.